# How to create a dynamic list with dynamic variables in a loop

Tags: python

In Python I'm trying to create a dynamic list with dynamic variable-names.

```
variable = dict()
x = 0
while (x < 10):
    for i in range(0, 10):
        variable[i] = i + 3   # just an example code
        print (i)
    x = x + 1
```

What I need is a list of every variable[i] for every x. But when I create this variable[i], I cannot ad another value the second time...

Comment: how does the output look like in your mind? Can you edit the question with the desired outcome please?

Comment: Is there any reason you introduce a dictionary in your code example? I don't see a purpose for that in your question

Comment: `variable[i] = variable.get(i, 0) + i + 3`. And that is not a list, it's a dict.

Answer (score 2):

A key in a dictionary must be unique.

After the first for loop you have a dictionary with 1...10 as keys.
When you do the second loop you just override the values you had before.

Instead, You can aggregate the result, when I say aggregate I mean that you will sum the value of an existing key if he exist.

If the key does not exist than the result from `variable.get(i, 0)` would be 0.

```
variable = dict()
x = 0
while (x < 10):
    for i in range(0, 10):
        variable[i] = variable.get(i, 0) + i + 3   # just an example code
    x = x + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring parts of your code example that do not seem to be part of the actual question, you can add list items to a list with "append":

```
variable = [] # create empty list
for i in range(10): # range(10) is the same as range(0,10)
    variable.append(i+3)
    print(i)
```

Btw, no need for `while(x<10)` and `x=x+1` in your code, as a for-loop does exactly that for you.

Comment: I think you may have forgoten to replace the  `while(x<10)` with a proper for-loop

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your code defines `variable` to be:

```
{0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 6, 4: 7, 5: 8, 6: 9, 7: 10, 8: 11, 9: 12}
```

You can get the same result with this one-liner:

```
>>> {i: i + 3 for i in range(10)}
{0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 6, 4: 7, 5: 8, 6: 9, 7: 10, 8: 11, 9: 12}
```

Note that it usually doesn't make sense to use a dict with integer keys between 0 and `n-1`. For this, you could simply use a list with `n` elements:

```
>>> [i + 3 for i in range(10)]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Which means you could just write

```
>>> range(3,13)
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

If you want a list of lists or a dict of lists, you could use this structure:

```
>>> {i: [i + j for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)}
{0: [0, 1, 2], 1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [2, 3, 4]}

>>> [[i + j for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)]
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```